# DataTable Column data to combobox error

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, combobox

I want to display all the data from a datatable column in a combobox. The form is to order new stock and save into a database.

I followed this tutorial http://youtu.be/cdkDHkXyVFI
I get 2 error messages :

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments  
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'
```

The code:

```
public partial class neworderForm : Form
{

public neworderForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fillCombo();
}
void fillCombo()
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
    string Query = "select * from stockTBL; ";
    SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
    SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    SqlCeDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string sName = myReader.GetString("[Item Name]");
            comboItem.Items.Add(sName);
        }

        //displays a system error message if a problem is found
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

the error is on  `string sName = myReader.GetString("[Item Name]");`

Comment: Both errors are saying: use integer column index as the `GetString` argument, but not the column name.

Comment: Can you elaborate and give instructions of how to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working version:

```
myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("[Item Name]"));
```

Reference:

GetString:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx

GetOrdinal:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getordinal.aspx

Comment: Works perfectly. With the "[]" in the code it opens a messagebox saying "[Item Name]", so I removed them, and it functions how I need it to! thanks Andrea.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds! Yes, this is indeed the way to do it.

Comment: I shall do, although @LeeCambl answered with a very similar answer, I'll use yours 'cause you wrote it first! unless you guys want to fight over it ;)

Comment: Keep your answer though Lee, Others will find it informative.

Answer (score 3):

The GetString() method on System.Data.Common.DbDataReader takes the column number (an int) to return the value of the column specified by the int as a string. This int is called the "ordinal". What you can do is modify your code to read:

```
string sName = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("[Item Name]"));
```

Where the GetOrdinal() bit will return the column number for use in the GetString() bit.

Make sense? For stuff like this I tend to have a little read of the Intellisense stuff that pops up as you type to see which method I need - I can never remember them all!

Comment: Makes sense now its been explained, I don't understand how he got it to work in the video tutorial. Oh well, works perfectly now for me.

Answer (score 0):

don't use a string with that function. if you know the zero based column index pass it there